# Run Nant script as a Jenkins post build action

Tags: jenkins, hudson, nant, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

Is it possible to run a Nant script as a Jenkins post build action?

I get the option to run a script as a Build Step but not as a build action. Is there any particular plugin which enables this option.

The reason I am looking for this functionality is that I need to run a script which depends on the ArtifactDeployer post build action. If i specify the code in the build step it gets executed before the ArtifactDeployer and the build fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Post Build Task Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task)

[image: Plugin screenshot]

**edit**

One way of getting the build number if it's not working with this plugin is using the [Groovy Post Build Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin)

With it you can execute groovy code as a post build action, get the build number and execute NAnt

the build number is accessible from the following property

```
manager.build.number
```

Comment: Thanks this works. But I am not able to use the build variables ($BUILD_NUMBER) inside this script. Any idea how to access them in the post build script

Comment: that's odd, the environment variable BUILD_NUMBER  should work (accessed using $BUILD_NUMBER in *nix machines and %BUILD_NUMBER% in Windows), can you recheck? are you by any chance using the promoted build plugin? If so, the variable name should be PROMOTED_NUMBER

Comment: I'm checking now. Is it possible to access a custom variable as well? Since the BUILD_NUMBER is intrinsic to Jenkins, I also have another value which is not part of Jenkins

Comment: the %BUILD_NUMBER% doesnt work. I echoed it out of the nant script.I guess the values are available only to the build steps and not to the post builds 

[echo] Build Number: %BUILD_NUMBER%

Comment: hmm, i see, i've updated my answer with a different approach, take a look

Answer (score 0):

Post-build Actions -> Execute a set of script run after a build when it succeeds or fails. My experience shows that it only *sometimes* runs when a build is aborted.

As advised above, the Post-build Actions -> Post build task (via the named post task plug in) is always evaluated for run (regardless of the build exit status). Additional setting via phrase in the log ("Build was aborted") works reliable for me.

My problem was to run something even on an aborted build and post build task sorted out this problem.